# Dialyzer not detecting obvious type error in parametrized type

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I'm trying to understand how the dialyzer works with polymorphic/parametrized types. I understand that it is optimistic and will succeed if there is any path through the code that does not cause a crash; what I don't understand is how to use type variables, given this fact.

I have a simple recursive binary search tree type specification that is intended to produce a BST with values of only one type. I know that (for instance) atoms and integers are comparable in Erlang, but I don't want my BST to allow those comparisons. I wrote and exported a function `b/0` that builds a BST with an integer and an atom, and the dialyzer isn't compaining.

```erlang
-module(bst).

-export([add/2, b/0, new/1]).

-type bst(T) :: {T, bst(T), bst(T)} | nil.

-spec new(T) -> bst(T).

-spec add(T, bst(T)) -> bst(T).

new(Root) -> {Root, nil, nil}.

add(Val, nil) -> {Val, nil, nil};
add(Val, {Root, Left, Right}) ->
    case Val =< Root of
      true -> {Root, add(Val, Left), Right};
      false -> {Root, Left, add(Val, Right)}
    end.

% Why no type error here? Adding atom to bst(integer()),
% but type spec allows only same type.
b() -> N = new(8), add(why_no_type_error, N).
```

Running the dialyzer gives the following success result:

```
dialyzer-tests ❯ dialyzer bst.erl
  Checking whether the PLT /home/.../.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
  Proceeding with analysis... done in 0m0.12s
done (passed successfully)
```

I was able to make this example fail by editing my `add/2` spec as below:

```erlang
-spec new(integer()) -> bst(integer());
     (atom()) -> bst(atom()).

-spec add(integer(), bst(integer())) -> bst(integer());
     (atom(), bst(atom())) -> bst(atom()).
```

Is this in any way idiomatic, or is there a better way to do this? I would not necessarily want to elaborate each possible type for each possible operation on my tree.

Comment: Where do you tell dializer that T must be an integer or a number? Without this restriction, tour code is correct

Comment: In my opinion, it is not the right way to define specs. see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get no warning is the fact that unconstrained type variables in specs (i.e. those that have no `when` clause) are generalized and treated as `term()`.

Notice that in your example, even without maximal generalization, there is the possibility of the type `atom() | integer()` for instances of `T` in your code which would give no warnings.

I can't think of an example where use of a type variable leads to an error, as I don't fully understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and succinct. Just to clarify: since values of all types are also values of type `term()`, type variables are not restrictive in this case. I've added some code above, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting the first element of the tuple to an integer works

```
-module(bst).

-export([add/2, b/0, new/1]).

-type bst() :: {integer(), bst(), bst()} | nil.

-spec new(integer()) -> bst().

-spec add(integer(), bst()) -> bst().

new(Root) -> {Root, nil, nil}.

add(Val, nil) -> {Val, nil, nil};
add(Val, {Root, Left, Right}) ->
    case Val =< Root of
      true -> {Root, add(Val, Left), Right};
      false -> {Root, Left, add(Val, Right)}
    end.

% this will generate a warning with dialyzer,
% but compile and execute without error.
b() -> 
    N = new(8), 
    add(why_no_type_error, N).
```

Then you get the error you expect (plus a strange "Function b/0 has no local return" which is apparently a consequence of the contract break):

```
C:\git\XXXXX\src>dialyzer bst.erl
  Checking whether the PLT c:/Users/YYYYY/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
  Proceeding with analysis...
bst.erl:22: Function b/0 has no local return
bst.erl:24: The call bst:add
         ('why_no_type_error',
          N :: {integer(), 'nil', 'nil'}) breaks the contract
          (integer(), bst()) -> bst()
 done in 0m0.20s
done (warnings were emitted)
```

at run time:

```
1> c(bst).                
{ok,bst}
2> bst:b().
{8,nil,{why_no_type_error,nil,nil}}
```

**Note** the fact that dializer issues a warning does not prevent the code to compile and execute without error. You need to add guard in the code if you want to generate errors at run time

```
-module(bst).

-export([add/2, b/0, new/1]).

% this version of code has the same warning with dialyzer
% and issues an exception at run time

-type bst() :: {integer(), bst(), bst()} | nil.

-spec new(integer()) -> bst().

-spec add(integer(), bst()) -> bst().

new(Root) when is_integer(Root) -> {Root, nil, nil}.

add(Val, nil) when is_integer(Val) -> {Val, nil, nil};
add(Val, {Root, Left, Right}) when is_integer(Val) ->
    case Val =< Root of
      true -> {Root, add(Val, Left), Right};
      false -> {Root, Left, add(Val, Right)}
    end.

b() -> 
    N = new(8), 
    add(why_no_type_error, N).
```

at run time:

```
3> c(bst).                
{ok,bst}
4> bst:b().               
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    bst:add(why_no_type_error,{8,nil,nil}) (bst.erl, line 13)
```